# HTML E-mail Has Overlapping Text

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-email, spacing

I'm designing an HTML E-mail for my company and am having issues with the HTML headings overlapping some text. I took the code from MailChimp as a template. When it's in mailchimp, it looks spaced out.

Edit: Had to remove some of the code because of the character limit. Only removed the footer and bottom portions that I don't think effect the spacing..

How it should look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Iyic.jpg

How it turns out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrEoZ.jpg

Below is the code. I know HTML E-mails are a pain, so I'm looking for any help or advice to deal with this spacing.

Thanks,

```
    <tbody><tr>
                                <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
                                    <table id="templatePreheader" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #eeeeee;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid #62788f;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td class="preheaderContainer" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top"><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29c2f7e911bc475a4dbf594d4/images/0ca55a16-7d7a-4c52-8b15-1855d5ad0765.png" style="margin: 0px;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;height: auto !important;" height="48" align="none" width="88"><strong><span style="font-size:14px"> &nbsp; &nbsp;<br>
<span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:12px">We put the friendly in 'Technology friendly'.</span></span></span></strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                    <!-- // END PREHEADER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                                    <table id="templateHeader" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #eeeeee;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 1px outset #62788f;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td class="headerContainer" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top"><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:60px"><strong>The IT Upload</strong></span><br>
<br>
<span style="font-size:18px"><strong>We've rebooted for Fall 2015!</strong><br>
<br>
<span style="font-size:16px">After a few months powered off, the IT Upload's batteries are recharged and ready to keep Drogans up to snuff with the latest tips, techniques, updates, and info for you to continue kicking ass with your technology! There’s a lot of exciting things happening over at the IT Department so stay tuned in the next few weeks. Yes smart ass, exciting things DO happen in IT sometimes!</span></span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                    <!-- // END HEADER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN COLUMNS // -->
                                    <table id="templateColumns" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #eeeeee;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td class="columnsContainer" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
                                                <table class="templateColumn" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td class="leftColumnContainer" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top"><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <h3 class="null" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;line-height: 125%;letter-spacing: -.5px;text-align: left;color: #EEEEEE !important;"><strong><span class="mc-toc-title"><span style="color:#62788f"><span style="font-size:25px">APPL</span></span><span style="color:#62788f"><span style="font-size:25px">E SELF SERVICE OF THE MONTH</span></span></span></strong></h3>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <span style="font-size:15px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif">Need to update your MacBook's Adobe Creative Cloud applications? NBD!<br>
<br>
<strong>NOTE: Be sure you quit any open Adobe applications first</strong><br>
<br>
1) Launch the Self Service application located in your applications folder.<br>
2) Select updates on the right side.<br>
3) Click 'Install' on Adobe updates and<br>
4) You're done. Bask in the glow of your tech accomplishment</span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <h2 style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 18px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: -.75px;text-align: left;color: #eeeeee !important;"><span style="color:#62788f"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:24px">NEW APP FROM VERIZON KEEPS YOU CONNECTED</span></span></span></h2>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <span style="font-size:15px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif">DROGA5 Telecommunications is in the midst of demoing an exciting new application that puts the power of a desk phone into your pocket! It is the phone version of the Virtual Communications Express software pre-installed on every Droga5 computer. If you are constantly using your desk phone and would like to help us trial this application, <strong>e-mail telecommunications@droga5.com.</strong></span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <h2 class="hP" id=":1ze" tabindex="-1" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 18px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: -.75px;text-align: left;color: #eeeeee !important;"><span style="color:#62788f"><span style="font-size:24px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif">ATTENTION DROGANS WITH BROKEN iDEVICES!</span></span></span></h2>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif">Don't let a cracked screen slow you down. We've partnered with the Device Repair Shop at <span class="il">One</span> <span class="il">Liberty</span> <span class="il">Plaza</span> to offer you complete screen repairs. iPhones for $100 and iPads for $108 with same day service. This should be a great option for those who do not have AppleCare or if your device is out of warranty.<br>
<br>
E-mail us at ITSupport@droga5.com if this sounds like you and we will assist in getting your device repaired. You've got nothing to lose, and a sexy, fresh device to gain.</span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="columnsContainer" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" valign="top" width="50%">
                                                <table class="templateColumn" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td class="rightColumnContainer" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top"><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <h2 style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 18px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: -.75px;text-align: left;color: #eeeeee !important;"><span style="color:#62788f"><span style="font-size:24px"><strong><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif">A FRIENDLY REMINDER ABOUT PASSWORDS</span></strong></span></span></h2>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif">We've noticed an unusual number of computers and phones just lying around the office unattended lately. We understand that this office is a place where you should be comfortable and able to relax but PLEASE DON'T LEAVE TECHNOLOGY UNATTENDED. We also want to make sure that everyone takes a few seconds to add a pass code to their mobile phones if you don't already have one.</span></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                            <h2 style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 18px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: -.75px;text-align: left;color: #eeeeee !important;"><span style="color:#62788f"><span style="font-size:22px"><strong><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,lucida grande,lucida sans unicode,lucida sans,tahoma,sans-serif">DON'T GET CAUGHT ON A PHISHER'S HOOK! PROTECT YOURSELF AND DROGA5...</span></strong></span></span></h2>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">

                <table class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding: 9px 18px;color: #62788F;font-family: &quot;trebuchet ms&quot;: ;,&quot;: ;lucida grande&quot;: ;lucida sans unicode&quot;: ;lucida sans&quot;: ;,tahoma,sans-serif: ;font-size: 18px;line-height: 100%;text-align: left;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;" valign="top">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to change the line height of your h2's to 125%, like this:

```
<h2 style="margin: 0;padding: 0;display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 18px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 125%;letter-spacing: -.75px;text-align: left;color: #eeeeee !important;">
```

Comment: if this works for you please click the check mark :)

Comment: perfect i'm glad i could help